# PHP Script to update multiple columns in a MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I need to update multiple columns in a single table in a single database.
Right now when I run my PHP script it only completes the first UPDATE command, it does not update the entries following it. I'm not sure what is wrong with it:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pw";
$dbname = "database";

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=10";
$sql="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=17";
$sql="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=22";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

When I run it from command line, it does not error out, it does run the first update just fine. When I go check on the database it has in fact updated the "team_id" to '15' in the "topic_id" column that has the id of "10", but the other two columns are not updated. Why is this?

Comment: you have to call mysql_query once for each sql statement. currently you're overwriting the statements with one another, so only the last is actually sent to the db (not the first)

Comment: This isn't multiple columns, it's multiple rows.

Comment: Why not use `WHERE topic_id IN (10, 17, 22)` to do them all in one query?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining the same variable over and over again, stomping the previous version. Only the last definition "sticks" and is run.

Either switch to an array:

```
// Define an array
$sql = [ ];
// Append to the array each query
$sql[] = "UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=10";
$sql[] = "UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=17";
$sql[] = "UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=22";

foreach($sql as $q) {
  // Run query.
}
```

Or use the `IN (...)` approach:

```
UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id IN (10,17,22)
```

Where one query can update multiple values to the *same thing*.

Comment: thank you! I was not aware of the IN command. Extremely useful.

Comment: Technically it'd be called a "clause" as part of a "WHERE condition". A "command" is something like `SELECT` or `INSERT`, usually the first word of the SQL statement. This might seem like an academic distinction, but the right terminology helps explain your requirements better, as well as what you've done to others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute every line:

```
//1
$sql="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=10";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

//2
$sql="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=17";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

//2
$sql="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=22";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

or create an array

```
$arra = array();
$arra[]="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=10";
$arra[]="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='11' WHERE topic_id=12";
$arra[]="UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='12' WHERE topic_id=13";
```

and foreach:

```
foreach ($arra as $sql) {

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using simply an "OR" operator will fix it!

```php
$sql = "UPDATE ost_help_topic SET team_id='15' WHERE topic_id=10 OR topic_id=12 OR topic_id=13"
```